# React native: read from a smartwatch (hk85)

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, sony-smartwatch

I'm trying to receive data from a smartwatch (HK85) in react native.
The connection and writing is working great.
But neither notify nor read is working.
And I guess that's normal since isNotifiable is set to false and read as well.

```
"_activePromises": {},  "_activeSubscriptions": {}, "deviceID":"8E:75:D1:20:6A:2B", "id":4, "isIndicatable":false, "isNotifiable":false, "isNotifying":false, "isReadable":false, "isWritableWithResponse":true, "isWritableWithoutResponse":true, "serviceID":3, "serviceUUID":"6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e", "uuid":"6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e"
```

What I don't understand is the fact that I have a SDK for Android (that comes with the watch) and basically when they want access to say the battery of the device, it writes data to it and then receives a package:

```
BleConnector sendData -> 0x0203_POWER, 0x10_READ
V/BaseBle: BleMessenger enqueueMessage -> WriteMessage(service='6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e', characteristic='6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e', data=0xAB, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03, 0xFC, 0xA0, 0x02, 0x03, 0x10
V/BaseBle: MessageTask -> try(1), WriteMessage(service='6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e', characteristic='6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e', data=0xAB, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03, 0xFC, 0xA0, 0x02, 0x03, 0x10
V/BaseBle: BleMessenger enqueueWritePackets -> WriteMessage(service='6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e', characteristic='6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e', data=0xAB, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03, 0xFC, 0xA0, 0x02, 0x03, 0x10
I/BaseBle: AbsBleConnector onCharacteristicWrite -> 0 SUCCESS, 6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e, 0xAB, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03, 0xFC, 0xA0, 0x02, 0x03, 0x10
V/BaseBle: BleMessenger dequeueWritePacket
I/BaseBle: AbsBleConnector onCharacteristicChanged -> 6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e, 0xAB, 0x11, 0x00, 0x04, 0x87, 0xFD, 0x02, 0x03, 0x10, 0x54
V/BaseBle: BleParser -> data length=10, received=10
```

So I'm a bit stuck at understanding how this works and I guess some answer reside in the onCharacteristicChanged, but how does that translate with this library?

Thank you for your time

Tried using react-native-ble-plx
**Tried first response**

```
deviceConnection.monitorCharacteristicForService(
        SERVICE_UUID,
        TX_CHARACTERISTIC,
        (error, char) => {
          console.log("Last data: " + char?.value);
        },
      );
      
      deviceConnection.writeCharacteristicWithResponseForService(
        SERVICE_UUID,
        RX_CHARACTERISTIC,
        "0xAB, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03, 0xFC, 0xA0, 0x02, 0x03, 0x10"
      ).then((data) => {
        console.log(data?.value)
      })
```

But the monitor never fires unless I disconnect the device and then its value is undefined. Maybe what I'm writing to it is wrong

**Managed to decode data received with Android SDK**

So after a long talk with chatgpt, we manage to decode the data I was receiving with my react native app after sending data with the Android SDK.

So we had to decode the base64 string to big endian array of bytes which resulted for example:
Decoding qxEABK19AgMQMg== as big endian gives the following byte array:

0x32, 0x10, 0x03, 0x02, 0x7D, 0xAD, 0x04, 0x00, 0x11, 0xAB

With 0x32 being the last byte and converted in decimal giving me 50, exactly the percentage left of my smartwach.

But there is still the question as to what I should write to the device to receive it, maybe I need to convert my array of bytes to a base64 or maybe I should change how I receive and write data.

Comment: Did you use a generic BLE exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to take a look at the services and characteristics the smartwatch offers?

Comment: I used react-native-ble-plx library and I did find the same services present in the Android sdk but couldn't read from it. Here is what nrf connect give me service : 6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e Rx characteristic 6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e  TX characteristics with properties notify 6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e and 0x2902 as a descriptor

Answer (score 0):

The smartwatch seems to offer the [Nordic UART Service](https://developer.nordicsemi.com/nRF_Connect_SDK/doc/1.5.1/nrf/include/bluetooth/services/nus.html) for communication. Your comment including the UUIDs you received using nRF Connect shows the same UUIDs and characteristics.

The documentation I linked states that the RX characteristic can be written by either Write or Write Without Response. The TX allows notifications and will use them to give you the response to the send data.

> What I don't understand is the fact that I have a SDK for Android (that comes with the watch) and basically when they want access to say the battery of the device, it writes data to it and then receives a package

The SDK also matches the UART service. To implement something similar using react-native-ble-plx you need to activate and subscribe to the notifications of the TX characteristic. See the [documentation](https://github.com/dotintent/react-native-ble-plx/wiki/Characteristic-Notifying) for examples.

**EDIT:**
maybe something like this works:

```
device.monitorCharacteristicForService(
  SERVICE_UUID,
  TX_CHARACTERISTIC,
  (error, char) => {
    console.log("Last data: " + char?.value);
  },
);

device.writeCharacteristicWithResponseForService(
  SERVICE_UUID,
  RX_CHARACTERISTIC,
  "0xAB, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03, 0xFC, 0xA0, 0x02, 0x03, 0x10"
)
```

Create the listener first, then write to the characteristic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Am I right in doing the monitoring first the TX char and inside it writing to the RX char like so: `device.monitorCharacteristicForService( SERVICE_UUID,TX_CHARACTERISTIC, (error, char) => {device.writeCharacteristicWithResponseForService(SERVICE_UUID,RX_CHARACTERISTIC, "0xAB, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03, 0xFC, 0xA0, 0x02, 0x03, 0x10").then((data) => {console.log(data) })console.log("Last data: " + char?.value); }, );`  or should it be the inverse first write and then monitor ? But in both case I got no console.log returned with the data

Comment: @lauren_d Inline code in comments is quite hard to read, but as far as I see thats probably not what you want to do. Right now you write to RX ONLY if you get a notification from TX (which you wont get because you never write to RX). I just added a small example (untested as I am not a react developer)

Comment: Tried your code but its the same, the monitor function doesn't seem to fire until I disconnect the device and then the data is null and of course its value undefined or maybe what I'm writing to it is wrong hence why it's not responding to it

Comment: Please use the nRF Connect app to write your data to the smartwatch and observe the notifications there. You can activate notifications for a specific characteristic by tapping the symbol of multiple arrows on the right side of the characteristic. Would be interesting to see if this works or if there are more steps required

Comment: I tried and it did nothing, I'm almost positive that what I'm writing to it is not good. Plus I did tried to run the sdk that I have after starting monitoring with my react native app and I started receiving notifications ! So for example after trying to read my battery with the sdk, my react native app returned this: "qxEABKh9AgMQPg=="

Comment: I can only guess now, but maybe the manufacturer wants to force you to use their SDK. Without knowing what messages you need to send to receive information this will be hard. Especially with a service like the UART service you want to use. There is no limit on what the manufacturer can send on your request

Comment: I will first try to use a buffer and sending the data that I have, will see what it does and update here

Comment: I managed to decode the base64 string I had to a percentage